# Must I reduce USB's 1A output to 450mA?

Tags: usb, charging, ac-adapter

I have a bluetooth headset that charges at direct current 5 Volt and 450 Milliampere. I charge it with its original AC-DC-converter and I want to be able to charge it over USB (e.g. from a portable pre-charged battery/charger or a solar USB charger).

I could easily cut the cable and solder the one end to a charging USB cable, but with this I would almost always give 5 Volt and 1 Ampere since that is the standard, right?

- Are there modified USB "cables" with extra electrical components on the market that use 500mA from 1A?
- Is there a DIY way to take out those 650mA or 500mA?

Comment: The device will only draw 500ma

Comment: really?! by closing the circuit I would only get as much as the battery of the headset demands? this means the 450mA on the AC-DC-adapter are printed to advice users that at more mA it might burn the internal circuit of the charger??

Comment: @scjorge Yes; Really!

Comment: This logic must be based on Grassman Algebra or something...

Comment: I wonder why someone downvote my question...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law

Comment: @DanielB Kirchhoff's Rules are more accurate

Comment: @DanielB, The simple Ohm or Kirchhoff formulas are applicable to circuit components with constant parameters. The AD-DC adapter is not a linear voltage source, and it will either abruptly reduce the voltage output when connected load exceeds its rated DC current capability (either along some artificially defined cut-off function, or just turn off). The device is also a non-linear load, starting with constant current, which will be reduced when the internal battery enters a constant voltage stage of charging. So these simple formulas do not apply.

Comment: @AliChen Ohm’s law provides a suitable abstraction for most people. Of course you can always go into further detail, but why bother?

Comment: @DanielB, I believe that the details are necessary because otherwise some curious people get confused with the discrepancy between their expectations and measured results.

Comment: @AliChen, the adapter may be non-linear, but the load is defined by Ohm's law.  I would add a comma to your first comment: Kirchoff might seem relevant after some grass, man.

Comment: @fixer1234, certainly the load is defined by Ohm's Law, if you mean that to consume 450mA from 5V it must have about 11 Ohms of **effective resistance**. However, there is a bunch of active elements that make this "impression", and this "resistor" will change in time as charging mode changes. So, given an unknown state of battery in the device when you plug it in first, you never know what its resistance is. How does the Ohm Law help here? So I am unsure what the objection is.

Comment: @AliChen, you're correct.  Where I was going is that we aren't designing the system.  The question was whether a 1 A charger would damage the headset.  While the effective resistance isn't fixed, there always is one, and it will be at least the value that defines the maximum current the headset draws.  So Ohm's law is enough to explain that the charger won't damage the headset.  But actually, my previous Ohm's law comment was just a setup for a lame joke.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't need to reduce anything. The headset is designed with a particular internal battery that has particular charging specifications, and its circuitry will not take more than whatever it is designed for (450mA in your case), no matter how capable the 5V source is, 1A or 10A or 30A.
2. FYI, USB cables do not "demand" anything. At most, if they have Type-C connector, they can inform the power provider and consumer about its wire gauge (current carrying capability). But you will be had pressed to find any of them yet.

Comment: I updated my question so I think the 2nd part of your answer is superluos. I suggested an edit and would then  mark the answer with a green tick

Comment: I am not sure I should do this. You have expressed a fairly common misconception about USB cables, I've seen this a half dozen times on stackexchange. Even in your edited form you still did not get it - a cable is a mere wire, it can't "block" 500mA.

Comment: by modifyed "cable" I mean: wire plus electrical component

Comment: @scjorge I have rejected your edit. The second bullet could still useful for others who visit with a similar question to you

Comment: @AliChen... this issue of the mA has been going arround my mind these last days. What makes it possible that my phone and tablet charge faster with an AC-DC converter from HTC with 1.5A printed on than with their original (non-HTC) AC-DC converter with 1A printed on? should I open another question regarding this matter?

Comment: @scjorge:  Different adapters may advertise their capabilities in different ways, using China signature, Apple signature, Type-C CC signature, Battery Charging signature, Power Delivery protocol. I don't know which signature is used in your two adpters, and which signature is recognized by your phone, so I can't answer your question. Phones also will reduce current draw if the input voltage drops over connecting cable.

Comment: thanx for the answer! hmm.. ok. well, I also don't have that info. I guess I'll just keep looking and reading (: